# pushing messages as root to user using startx

Tags: command-line, raspberry-pi

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 running raspbian.

This little guy is going to basically be a media server.
I would like to be able to push messages when I `ssh` into the thing, but when I try to `echo "message" |write`, it doesn't show up on `startx`.

Is there away to create a popup that will flash in the corner on the television when its being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of ways. Like this simple one:

`echo "message" | DISPLAY=:0.0 xmessage -geometry -0+0 -timeout 5 -file -`

Any solution requires you have access to the X server, though.  So perhaps switch to the user owning the display first?